# How to translate "Closed" in Opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, picklist, translation, translation-workbench, stagename

How do I change the textual value of 'Closed' to "I like cheese" in English, and 「チーズが好き」 in Japanese?

[image]

"Closed" isn't an actual stage, so it's not in the "Stage" picklist translations:

[image]

And I've tried adding a translation under the "Forecast category" picklist translations, but this isn't reflected on the Opportunity record screen, even after several days:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, it still says "Closed". So how do I translate this value?

P.S. I also tried in Japanese to no avail (since the requirement I have received is to change it in both English *and* Japanese):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably not possible, is does not seem to be a picklist value that's being displayed. There have been a few known issues with path, some still remain, like this one: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eX1tAAE. There is also an idea to change the last stage behaviour: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNQKQA2.

Comment: @Fred That's disappointing if that's the case. Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the answer is "no".

I have no documentation to support it other than to say I see the same behavior you do even following all the scenarios presented in these answers.

When you change languages, it's automatically translated and it's the language-specific version of "Closed". The fact that it's **automatically translated** hints that this may be some standard value that you cannot change.

The screenshot @Roxana pasted shows an example as it shows the German word for "Closed". I see the same when setting my language to German, but I'm not able to change it to be a different word as you're asking (and as you can do for the custom picklist values). It seems it will always be the value of Closed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the Closed Won stage directly, but there is a workaround.
You can create a new picklist value with type as Closed/Won, give it a probability 100% and name it whatever you want then simply deactivate the standard Closed(Won) picklist value.

[image: Stage]

Hope it helped. Cheers!

Comment: That just seems to add it to the [Close This Opportunity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLT6R.png) screen, but doesn't change the name of the "Closed" button.

Comment: exactly which "Closed" button are you referencing to?

Comment: The one underlined in red in [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG0Zy.png) towards the top of my question.

Comment: Can you either answer my question or delete this answer? It makes it look like I have multiple answers, when in fact none of them address my question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setup-> Translation Workbench -> Translate.
Then select the component to be "Picklist values" and then the object "Oportunity" and translate the Forecast Category picklist values since Closed is a forecast category, not a stage. I tested in my dev org and it worked.

[image]

Comment: Hey folks, it seems like there's some mutual misunderstanding and frustration here so I'm going ahead and clearing out the comments. Let's let that be a reset and understand that for whatever reason it looks like this route isn't working out.

Answer (score 0):

In case the below editing of the Opportunity Path does not work, you may need to open a Salesforce Case and they can help further and give a definite answer to this.

Editing Path Step 1.[image]

Edit Path Step 2 [image]

Try editing the Path in Lightning Experience
Note for Lightning, these are now called Paths, formerly Sales Process

In lightning go to Setup-> Quick Find Box =- > Type Path Settings
Adjust the Path for Opportunity.  I believe that will work.
Reference: [image: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_migration_whatsnew/lex_migration_whatsnew_crm]

That is an Opportunity Stage. The reason you are not seeing it change is that you need to change the Sales Process from 'closed' to your new custom stage as well. Try this to edit and customize Opportunity Stages and make your custom stage for 100% - your own custom stage.  **This is key -> After that you need to change the Sales Process for that type of Opportunity to include the new stage that you made.**  then you will see it change

Switch to classic temporarily: Setup-> Customize->Opportunities->Fields->Stage

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/admin_intro_opptys_leads/admin_intro_opptys_leads_opportunities

Comment: [It's not a stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcLX1.png). It's not in the stage picklist. It's in the forecast category picklist, but translating the forecast category doesn't make a blind bit of difference. This has all been in my question from day one.

Comment: I know you are seeing a picklist but that picklist is getting its info from stages.  Every type of Opportunity has its own Sales Process which you can edit the process for custom stages.  The picklist you are referring to is making a call to the stages of your process to get its choices in the picklist.  Make a new stage and then change the process for the stage to end on your custom stage which will equal 100%

Comment: But even [Sales processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPAW5.png) doesn't show "Closed"? I must be missing something. Have you managed to change the text of "Closed" with the method you are suggesting?

Comment: Switch to classic temporarily:  Setup-> Customize->Opportunities->Fields->Stage

Comment: I've done so, but again I don't see "Closed". [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzYxb.png)

Comment: then create one with the New Button in that area and call it 'Finished' and have it be 100%

Comment: OK, and now what? Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76YwT.png) right?

Comment: Setup-> Customize->Opportunities->Sales Process  and create a new custom sales process for opportunities   and include your new stage you made

Comment: [Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOow0.png) - Now what?

Comment: then affiliate that new process with your opportunity and then test it.  You should have a new stage (custom) and a new opportunity sales process that shows that new stage at the end

Comment: Do I have to do that on an Opportunity-by-Opportunity basis?

Comment: you must test with a new opportunity - it will not change the old ones

Comment: It doesn't seem to have made much of a difference. I now see three options in [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bduy1.png): Lost, Won, Finished

Comment: if you have different types of opportunities like "Real Estate', 'Insurance' yes, you will have to modify each type of opportunity record type sales process.  If in the rare case you have that scenario

Comment: I don't have different types of opportunities. I haven't configured anything with this: _"Opportunity Record Type"_ -> _"No record types defined"_. But this still hasn't allowed me to change "Closed" to something else.

Comment: I'm beginning to think it isn't possible to change it.

Comment: I'm fairly convinced you had the wrong end of the stick with your answer. I'm not really sure why people found my question unclear, but I've edited it to try and make it even clearer. Do you have any suggestions that I haven't already tried?

Comment: when you first posted the question I believe you were calling it a 'button' or something like that which threw me off, I believe you have edited the question.  It is a stage.  All you have to do is now ensure your Sales process is what you have told it to do.  Why not switch over to classic to verify that is working first in classic mode.  if that shows correctly, then let me know.

Comment: [You can view the first revision here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/revisions/305896/1). Regardless of terminology, the screenshot shows what I want to change clearly. Anyway, "Closed" does not appear in the sales process. Only "Closed Won" and "Closed Lost" appear in the sales process section. Nothing there allows translation of "Closed" anyway. This is true in Classic and Lightning. By the way, we only use Lightning because we're new to Salesforce.

Comment: The revision of the question you answered is [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/revisions/305896/6). If you read the entire question and don't skim it, it's clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I still believe what you are trying to do is possible, however, when I have issues with lightning I always prove it is possible with classic first, then I will try it with lightning.  Its a stage and then it's a Sales process that uses that stage.

Comment: Except Closed doesn't appear in the [list of stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcLX1.png). I'm told that it's a "forecast category" but changing it there doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Try Salesforce Path in Lightning as I added to my answer just now

Comment: So, as per your advice last week I created a [sales process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpimT.png), and that's reflected in the [path settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcSWv.png) today. I don't have [multiple record types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkYNw.png), so I would expect this to work off the bat for any new opportunity. Unfortunately, I [still see Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpTc9.png).

Comment: I have explained the exact process how to edit the Salesforce Opportunity Stage and Sales process and a new Lightning Path for Opportunity.  The only thing you can do now is open a Salesforce Case because maybe it has to do with the Org switch over to German Language, perhaps there is a bug.  Salesforce will help you out with a Case at this point.  I hope I have helped as much as possible.

Comment: But in your guide "Closed" always appears as closed. It doesn't appear as anything else. I'm still convinced that you don't understand what I'm trying to do. Thank you very much for trying though. I do appreciate it.

Comment: exactly all of those are normally editable even closed can be replaced as you have seen last week. Salesforce is very good with answering cases.  They usually turn around in a day or two most.  There is something different with yours from my understanding.